# jQuery - Validate Password

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to use jQuery to validate my two password fields with each other.

My code looks like this:

```
jQuery('#settingsForm').validate(
    rules : {
        npassword : {
        },
        pass_check : {
            equalTo : '#npassword'
        }
    }
});
```

This is the HTML for the input fields:

```
<label for='npassword'>New Password</label>
<input type='password' class='span10 password_check' name='npassword' id='npassword' value='' placeholder='New Password'>
<div class='separator'></div> 

<label for='pass_check'>Confirm New Password</label>
<input type='password' class='span10' name='pass_check' id='pass_check' value='' placeholder='Confirm New Password'>
<div class='separator'></div>
```

Although this doesn't do anything. What should I change? I am new to jQuery and Javascript in general.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `equalTo : '#password'` should be `equalTo : '#npassword'`, as thats the ID of the other element.

Comment: You need to pass the input names, not the label names.

Comment: Oh, of course. But it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fill out the configuration for `npassword`, e.g. by using `required: true`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/JtTgM/

Comment: Thanks! How can I change the standard message "Please enter the same value again"?

Comment: You can override ′messages′ as you can see here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You are missing an opening brace, `{`, right after `.validate(`:

```
jQuery('#settingsForm').validate({ // <-- opening brace { was missing
```

**2)** Maybe you want to specify the `required` rule for the first password field. Otherwise, when both fields are blank, they both match and the form is valid.

```
npassword: {
    required: true
},
```

**3)**  You can override the default messages with the `messages` option:

```
jQuery('#settingsForm').validate({
    rules: {
        npassword: {
            required: true
        },
        pass_check: {
            equalTo: '#npassword'
        }
    },
    messages: {
        npassword: {
            required: "this field is required"
        },
        pass_check: {
            equalTo: "the passwords must match"
        }
    }
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/vsLWg/**

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#Form").validate({
  rules: {
    old_password: "required",
    password: "required",
    new_password: {
      equalTo: "#password"
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: share your issue or problem

Comment: Please add some description to your post. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer